# Generics and Anonymous types

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, anonymous-types

I have a function,

```
public static IPagedResponse<T> GetPagedResponse<T, TAnon>(
        this IQueryable<TAnon> query, 
        QueryableRequestMessage request)
    where T : class
{
    //...
}
```

I'm trying to pass query as an `IQueryable` of an anonymous type.

```
var query = _repository.All.Select(
    i => new //anon type
        {
            i.Id,
            i.Name,
        }
    );

var result = query.GetPagedResponse<EftInterfaceDto, ??????>(request);
```

The issue is I don't know what to put in place of `??????`?  It can't seem to infer it.  And any combinations using `.GetType()` or `typeof()` I have tried, failed.

I tried changing the function to be `IQueryable<dynamic>` but that resulted in other errors, about dynamic not being allowed in Expression trees.

**HACK:**

I can make it work if I change my function to this:

```
public static IPagedResponse<T> GetPagedResponse<T, TAnon>(
        this IQueryable<TAnon> query, 
        QueryableRequestMessage request,
        T typeSample)
    where T : class
{
    //...
}
```

And then pass in an instance of `T`

```
var result = query.GetPagedResponse(request, new SomeClassOfT());
```

This way, I can use type inference to determine the anonymous type `TAnon`, and don't need to be explicit in the call to the generic (no `<types>` required).

However, I don't want to do this, as it's clearly not clear what I'm doing.

Comment: That is the type `TAnon` used for in the method?
You can't parse anonymous types as a generic parameter.

Perhaps there is another way to achive your goal?

Comment: You have an extra comma after `i.Name`, if you typed it like that in VS, it might have trouble inferring the type.

Comment: Try using the function not as an extension method. Type inference on extension methods is sometimes weaker than otherwise.